# Breaking the maximum number of refiners, limited to 20 in SharePoint 2013 search

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, refinement-panel, refiner

The SharePoint project I'm currently working on uses a custom search results page.  We've customized the display templates, the search results webpart, and the refinement panel.

An enhancement to our system calls for the number of refiners to be increased from 19, to 21.  In the refinement configuration I was informed that "For performance reasons it is not allowed to select more than 20 refiners." and the option to add more refiners is disabled.  I wasn't aware of this, I couldn't find the answer on the net or from tinkering with the webpart, and it seems to be a hard limit.  Up to this point the message was "Selecting more than 10 refiners can degrade search performance" but the performance of the search has been more than adequate with 19 refiners.

**How can we break this limit of 20 refiners in SharePoint 2013 search?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not listed in the Boundaries and Limits document, but it does appear to be a hard limit. Though it is only enforced by the UI. You can use F12 developer tools to remove the "disabled" attribute from the button and add more. I tested and added 23 through the UI.

The other approach would be to export the web part and add additional Managed Properties to the SelectedRefinementControlsJson property.

Kudos to Mikael Svenson for the answer. He detailed it in this post: http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-add-more-than-20-refiners-to.html